# Rename files in R

Tags: r, unicode, file-rename

I have problem with renaming files from `R`.

In my folder on Desktop there are 10 files:

`račun 1.xlsx`

`račun 2.xlsx`

...

`račun 10.xlsx`

I have tried the following:

```
files <- list.files(path = "myfolder")
file.rename(files,
        paste0("novi_", 1:10, ".xlsx"))
```

This is what I get as an outcome:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I suppose this is because of unicode character č, but I do not know how to find a solution for this.

Comment: Side note: it might be safer to do `paste0("novi_", seq_along(files), ".xlsx")` ...

Comment: Do you get any warnings, or just the logical vector returned. What's the output of `file.exists("račun 1.xlsx")`

Comment: No warnings. Interesting, but `file.exists("račun 1.xlsx")` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: What are the first three lines of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252

Comment: That's your problem. Windows is looking for the file with the `"č"` as a  `"c"`.

Comment: How about `file.exists("racun 1.xlsx")`

Comment: Again `FALSE` . How can I fix this? Should I change my Windows options somewhere in Control Panel?

Comment: I made one more suggestion in an edit to my question below. I hope I've helped you diagnose the problem, but it doesn't look like I got you all the way to the goal line.

Comment: I have changed my Region settings in Control Panel, set format to be in Serbian(Latin, Serbia), and now it is working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT 2: The solution here was for the OP to change the Region settings in Control Panel, setting format to be in Serbian(Latin, Serbia).

EDIT 1: See the comments: the OP is on a Windows machine. Here the problem is that `list.files()` (and presumably `dir()`, since they call the same .Internal) is converting the non ASCII filenames to ASCII, but Windows is expecting `file.exists()` to send it the unicode filenames, (and presumably also `file.rename()`)

Try:

```
file.rename(gsub("c", "č", files), paste0("novi_", seq_along(files, ".xlsx"))
# could work, but it didn't for `file.exists()`
```

Original answer:

```
setwd(<your path>)
(files <- list.files())
# [1] "račun 1.xlsx" "račun 2.xlsx" "račun 3.xlsx" "račun 4.xlsx" "račun 5.xlsx [6] "račun 6.xlsx"    
file.rename(files, paste0("novi_", seq_along(files, ".xlsx"))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

The fact that you specified a path in `list.files()`, suggests that you're not in the correct directory

Comment: Still the same outcome.

Comment: @Luka This works on my machine. `file.rename()` "is subject to the limitations of the OS's corresponding system call." Can you do this in your shell?

Comment: Windows is perfectly capable of working with non-ASCII filenames. The Windows version of R has problems sometimes though.

Comment: Yes, this is the apparent problem. `list.files()` is returning the ASCII filenames, but when they're passed to `file.exists()`, Windows is expecting the non-ASCII file name.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this is to use the [8.3 version of a filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename), which is guaranteed to be ASCII-only. The main problem is that (as far as I know) there's no way to get this programmatically in R, so you should double-check that this is correct:

```
files <- paste0("RAUN~", 1:10, ".XLS")
newfiles <- paste0("novi_", 1:10, ".xlsx")
file.rename(files, newfiles)
```

You can get the 8.3 filenames with `DIR /X` from the commandline.